# how does nextDouble(); scan integer values?

Tags: java, integer, double, java.util.scanner

I'm new to coding and I wrote this code using nextDouble();, it reads both double and integer values. Is this right? How does that happen? This is my code,

```
    import java.util.*;
class Example{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
      double gram;
      double ounce;
      System.out.println("Input ounce:");
      ounce=input.nextDouble();
      System.out.println("ounce in gram:");
      gram=ounce*28.3495;
      System.out.println(gram);
   }
}
```

Comment: what is double scanner?

Comment: @IłyaBursov sorry that was a mistake

Comment: still not sure what the question is, but - scanner is reading strings and only strings, but then you can use nextint/nextdouble methods which convert string into appropriate type

Comment: @DewzD and Integer is a floating point without decimals. That's why, a string containing an integer can be seen either as Integer and Double.

Comment: @IłyaBursov if I use nextDouble, does it scans input data as an "int"?

Comment: @LucaScarcia ohh right I got it now, thank you so much

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The Scanner is using ',' for it's next.Double(). You can simply change this by adding the Countries locale.

```
input.useLocale(Locale.US);
```

This should be placed before you set the value of ounce:

```
input.useLocale(Locale.US);
ounce = input.nextDouble();
```